# Can't execute sql file

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm trying to execute the following code using isql:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'SFPTB051_ABERTURARCLH'))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM SFPTB051_ABERTURARCLH;
END
```

The way i'm doing:

```
isql -i sql_scripts/test.sql  _input/mygdb.GDB -user SYSADM -pass masterkey
```

Output:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -104
-Token unknown - line 1, column 1
-IF
At line 1 in file sql_scripts/test.sql
Expected end of statement, encountered EOF
```

Any ideias?

Thanks!

UPDATE ---

I'm trying the following:

```
SET TERM # ;

EXECUTE BLOCK AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM SFPTB051_ABERTURARCLH
END#

SET TERM ; #
```

But it's returning:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -104
-Token unknown - line 4, column 1
-END
```

Comment: `if` can only be used inside a sproc. it's not a valid query command by itself.

Comment: Take a look at `EXECUTE BLOCK`. It should do the trick.

Comment: Could u give me a example?

Comment: I have updated @RenéHoffmann can you take a look?

Comment: You're missing the statement terminator `;` at the end of the `SELECT` in your `EXECUTE BLOCK`.

Comment: Note that your first piece of code on Firebird won't work at all as Firebird doesn't have the SQL standard `information_schema` tables and views.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, select statements within a block statement need to return their values. For example, you can return them into variables or return values, which are almost the same.

Furthermore, every statement within a block statement has to be terminated by a semi-colon (`;`).

Your block statement could look something like this:

```
SET TERM # ;

EXECUTE BLOCK AS
DECLARE VARIABLE FIELD1 TYPE OF COLUMN SFPTB051_ABERTURARCLH.FIELD1;
/* declare more variables as needed */
BEGIN
  FOR
    SELECT FIELD1
    FROM SFPTB051_ABERTURARCLH
    INTO :FIELD1
  DO
  BEGIN
    /* do something with the variables values */
  END
END#

SET TERM ; #
```